# Javascript HTML string into array of tags and inner content

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split, match

I am trying to match on HTML tags and their inner content and put each match into an array (both the tag and its inner contents).

I was able to match the tags themself and put those into an array, but I'm not sure how to get the inner contents of the tag as well.

```
// Example String
let str = "<p><b>Label:</b>Value<p></p><p><b>New Line Label:</b>Value 2</p></p>";
console.log(str.match(/\<.*?\>/gi)) // Output ["<p>", "<b>", "</b>", "<p>", "</p>", "<p>", "<b>", "</b>", "</p>", "</p>"]


// Expected Output
["<p>", "<b>", "Label:", "</b>", "Value", "<p>", "</p>", "<p>", "<b>", "New Line Label:", "</b>", "Value 2", "</p>", "</p>"]
```

Can this be handled in a single regex match, or do I need to match and then look back to the closing previous tag to get the inner content?

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOMParser API and then keep iterating through childrens of each node

```js
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<p><b>Label:</b>Value<p></p><p><b>New Line Label:</b>Value 2</p></p>', 'text/html')

console.log(doc.children) // DOM nodes
```

with this you'll have constructed a complete DOM from string you have then apply any function you'd like on it